# Removing node from a totally black red black tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I am reading the [Wikipedia explanation of red black tree removal process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal).

There is one simple thing which I am not able to understand.

Example: I have a totally black RBTree

```
                     3(B)
                 /          \
                /            \
               1(B)          5(B)
             /     \        /    \
            /       \      /      \
           0(B)     2(B) 4(B)     6(B)
```

Wikipedia states that if you have a node to delete with 2 leaf children and the sibling is also a node with 2 Leaf children, then we can simply remove the node and recolor the parent and sibling.

Suppose in the tree above I want to delete 0. Then no amount of recoloring 1 or 2 helps because no matter what you do, the two subrees (the 1 side) and the 5 side end up with different black heights.

What am I missing?

I found that Wikipedia had a very good explanation of insert, but the explanation of delete is confusing.

Comment: "Wikipedia states that if you have a node to delete with 2 leaf children and the sibling is also a node with 2 Leaf children, then we can simply remove the node and recolor the parent and sibling." - I'm not seeing that in the article. This looks to me like it's covered under Removal, M and C are both black, case 3. Look for the bold **Case 3** under **Removal**.

Comment: In that case, the article says to delete the node, repaint its sibling red, and then rebalance the parent.

Comment: So as per case 3 we will recolor node 2 to Red and try again from case 1. In this case... case 1 won't do anything but case 2 would rotate the tree making 2 the child of 3, then 1R will be the child of 2 and finally 0B will be the child of 1.

now if we remove 0, the b-height on the left tree is still 3 whereas on the right hand side is 4.

Comment: can you please explain the simple case above? I was not able to decipher the answer form wikipedia.

Comment: You almost got it but then you made a mistake by jumping to case 2 - you should have jumped to case 3 again, then case 1 and finish. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting node "0" in your tree is actually the most complicated case. Let's follow the [description from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal) step by step:

> We use the label M to denote the node to be deleted; C will denote a
>   selected child of M, which we will also call "its child". If M does
>   have a non-leaf child, call that its child, C; otherwise, choose
>   either leaf as its child, C.

So, in this case, M is your node "0", which will be deleted, and C is any of its NIL children (leaves, which are always NIL). Just to remind, your original tree - following your beautiful ascii-art is:

```
                     3(B)
                 /          \
                /            \
               1(B)          5(B)
             /     \        /    \
            /       \      /      \
           0(B)     2(B) 4(B)     6(B)
```

So M is "0", and note that C (the NIL leaf) is not painted here. The wikipedia follows:

> The complex case is when both M and C are black *(this is our case)*.... In the diagrams
>   below, we will also use P for N's new parent (M's old parent), SL for
>   S's left child, and SR for S's right child.

So, P is "1", and S is "2", all nodes are black. Then you follow the case descriptions. You skip case 1, as "0" is not root. You skip case 2, as "2" is not red. Case 3 is matching:

> **Case 3:** P, S, and S's children are black. In this case, we simply repaint S red. The result is that all paths passing through S, which
>   are precisely those paths not passing through N, have one less black
>   node. Because deleting N's original parent made all paths passing
>   through N have one less black node, this evens things up. However, all
>   paths through P now have one fewer black node than paths that do not
>   pass through P, so property 5 (all paths from any given node to its
>   leaf nodes contain the same number of black nodes) is still violated.
>   To correct this, we perform the rebalancing procedure on P, starting
>   at case 1.

So at this point, you delete "0", and repaint S = "2" red:

```
                     3(B)
                 /          \
                /            \
               1(B)          5(B)
                   \        /    \
                    \      /      \
                    2(R) 4(B)     6(B)
```

Then, following the description, you go to Case 1, but this time with its parent node P (= "1") substitued as N. But N = "1" is not root, so you jump to Case 2. S = "5" is not red, so we jump to Case 3 again. And here, we re-paint S = "5" red:

```
                     3(B)
                 /          \
                /            \
               1(B)          5(R)
                   \        /    \
                    \      /      \
                    2(R) 4(B)     6(B)
```

Then we have to jump to Case 1 again, with P = "3" substitued as N this time. N = "3" and we see that this is a root, **so we are done! The tree is balanced!**